# iOS Images, photokit, image orientation

Tags: ios, ios8, photokit

I am working on an iOS app using iOS 8 and the new PhotoKit, I iterate over user images and I am trying to find out via code whether an image is vertical or horizontal? is there a flag I can inspect on the asset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:` to request a image and get its orientation through `imageOrientation` property. See the doc here [requestImageForAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best response but maybe it can help:

You can check if `pixelWidth` of `PHAsset` object is larger than `pixelHeight` to detect if it is horizontal or not. You can also write category in order to provide a flag which is BOOL to make your code looks cleaner.